# Copy information from variable sheets to sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure where to begin, I have found codes for finding information and selecting it so that the information can be modified. However I'm not sure how to even begin to start a string that I need as I am new to vba.

I will begin by explain what my current "macro1" does. I have 2 main sheets in excel, the first is "template" and the other is "log". "Macro" copies information from "template" sheet and pastes it on "form" after it has created a new row. Then it copies it's self and renames the sheet to value "A1". It then reassigns a macro to the button (macro2).

Over time you have multiple sheets with macro2. What I'm trying to do is have macro2 copy the information in a cell range on the active sheet to "log" sheet. It needs to find the cell "A1" from the previously active sheet and replace the information.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatful.

Comment: Showing us your current code would be a good start.